# How to install xcode 7 and edit Swift 2.X on macOS Mojave version 10.14.3

Tags: xcode7, xcode10, macos-mojave, swift2

In Case, 
My project is using swift 2.X .
Once i installed Xcode 10. Xcode 10 is not available to code swift 2.X.
So i have to installed oldest version,
i go installed Xcode version 7.X , but not available to run on OS with the following problem message.

```
Xcode cannot be opened because of a problem.
Check with the developer to make sure Xcode works with this version of
macOS. You may need to reinstall the application.Be sure to install any
available updates for the application and macOS.
```

Any Solution to solve my problem??

Comment: have you got any solution to this? I have got a project which is on Swift3.x whereas my machine is having MacOS mojave and Xcode10.